# How do I make a specific factor in a vector have a higher level than every other factor?

Tags: r

Given a vector for which "b" will always be an element of, how do I make "b" have a higher level than all the other factors (without reordering the other factors relative to each other)?

For example

```
> set.seed(1) # for reproducibility
> df<-data.frame(x=letters[c(2,sample(4,4,replace=TRUE))])
> df
  x
1 b
2 b
3 b
4 c
5 d
> levels(df$x)
[1] "b" "c" "d"
```

I'm not sure if I'm asking this correctly, but how do I make it so `levels(df$x) = "c","d","b"`

In other words, I want "b" to always show up last.

Comment: Do you want to keep the actual values in df$x the same but you just want 'b' to be considered the 'last'?

Comment: @Dason that's correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# Make some data
x <- c("a", "b", "c", "b", "a")
x <- factor(x)
> x
[1] a b c b a
Levels: a b c
```

We can respecify the factor with the ordering that we want

```
# save the current levels
lev <- levels(x)
# Find the one we want
# So change this to specify the level you want to be last
val <- which(lev == "b")
# Remake the factor specifying the order we want
x <- factor(x, levels = c(lev[-val], lev[val]))

> x
[1] a b c b a
Levels: a c b
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `levels(df$x) <- c('c', 'd', 'b')` work here?

Comment: The problem is that you don't what elements will or will not be in the vector (excluding b).